# how can I get the integers from a comma-delimited text

Tags: java

I have a text stream that only contains integers each seperated by a comma.
here is an example of what I have:

```
String text="143,136,159,140";
```

I need to extract every number one by one.
I tried something like that.

```
int placeHolder=0;
for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++) {
    if(text.charAt(i)==',') 
    {
        System.out.println(text.substring(placeHolder,i));
        placeHolder=i+1;
    }
}
```

The output has to be like this :

```
143
136
159
140
```

but I am getting this instead :

```
143
136
159
```

I couldn't manage to get last one.what is it that I m doing wrong

Comment: look at the split method in String, like split(",")

Comment: Your current code does not trigger at the end of line because there is no comma

Answer (score 1):

You code don't print the last number because you only print when found `,`. So for last number you don't do anything.
You need to add this line after for loop to print last number

```
System.out.println(text.substring(placeHolder));
```

Rather you can try this way to print inside the loop

```
int placeHolder=0;
for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++) {
    if(i == text.length()-1 || text.charAt(i+1)==',' ) 
    {
        System.out.println(text.substring(placeHolder,i+1));
        placeHolder=i+2;
    }

}
```

Or you can use `.split()`

```
String[] nums = text.split(",");
for (String num : nums) {
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.I will put those integers to a function one by one.So if I dont want to store the numbers I ll  use your previous loop  thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use split(",") like this:

```
    String[] numbers = text.split(",");
    for (String number : numbers) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
```

Comment: happy to here that

Answer (score 0):

Using streams, we can try:

```
String text = "143,136,159,140";
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.stream(text.split(","))
                            .map(Integer::valueOf)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, the code checks for a ',' and prints the integer before it. But there is no ',' after the last integer, so it is not printed. Instead, use `text.split(",");`